# Magento Slider Link

Tags: jquery, html, magento, hyperlink, slider

I have been trying to add a link to my entire slide on magento (not just the "read more" button, I was wondering if anyone can show me the right way to do this - I have tried wrapping the entire div in the slider_1 static block in a link tag but this has not worked and seems to break the slider text and button. I dont need the button if the image is linking.

Here is my code in the slider_1 static block (look at slide 3) this is where I added the link tag.

```
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{skin url='js/camera.js'}}">// <! [CDATA[

// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
                alignmen: 'topCenter',
                height: '31.21%',
                minHeight: '100px',
                loader : false,
                navigation: true,
                fx: 'simpleFade',
                navigationHover:false,       
                thumbnails: false,
                playPause: false,
                pagination:false,
            });
        });
// ]]></script>
<div class="fluid_container_wrap">
<div class="fluid_container">
<div id="camera_wrap" class="camera_wrap camera_orange_skin">
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/vineyard1.jpg'}}">
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/big-m.png'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title"></div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1"></div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/collection-bg.jpg'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title">MEN'S &amp;amp <br /> WOMEN'S</div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1">New Fall Season 2015</div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8">View Collection</a></div>
</div>
<a href="#"><div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/six-bg.jpg'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title">MEN'S &amp;amp <br /> WOMEN'S</div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1">New Fall Season 2015</div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8">View Collection</a></div>
</div></a>
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/buy-five-bg.jpg'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title">MEN'S &amp;amp <br /> WOMEN'S</div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1">New Fall Season 2015</div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8">View Collection</a></div>
</div>
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/brut-bg.jpg'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title lof_white">Get ready <br /> for summer!</div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1">Save in style</div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8">View Collection</a></div>
</div>
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/mille-bg.jpg'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title">MEN'S &amp;amp <br /> WOMEN'S</div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1">New Fall Season 2015</div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8">View Collection</a></div>
</div>
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/grande-bg.jpg'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title">MEN'S &amp;amp <br /> WOMEN'S</div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1">New Fall Season 2015</div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8">View Collection</a></div>
</div>
<div data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/classm-bg.jpg'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title">BUY <br />2 ITEMS</div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1">Get one for free</div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}accessories">View Collection</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

I have tried wrapping everything in a link and also just the image in a link but to no avail.

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.By adding

```
data-link="{{store url=collection}}"
```

to the image divs. It linked properly like so:
This is a Jquery plugin called "camera"

```
<div class="fluid_container_wrap">
<div class="fluid_container">
<div id="camera_wrap" class="camera_wrap camera_orange_skin">
<div data-link="{{store url=collection}}" data-src="{{skin    url='images/camera/slides/vineyard1.jpg'}}">
<div data-link="{{store url=collection}}" data-src="{{skin url='images/camera/slides/big-m.png'}}">
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromLeft">
<div class="lof_camera_title"></div>
<div class="lof_camera_title1"></div>
<a class="camera-link" href="{{store url=''}}women-8"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```